# Duplicate values ​when joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Initially I have these three tables:

**Data1**:

```
PK_data1
```

**Data2**:

```
PK_data2
data1
```

**Data3**:

```
PK_data3
data2
ext
```

I need to get the `data1` and `ext` columns so I try to inner join between `data1` and `data2`, and then `data2` and `data3`, thus removing the elements. The problem is that it extracts additional values ​​from me.

```
SELECT  d1.PK_data1, d2.PK_data2, d3.ext
FROM data1 d1
JOIN data2 d2 ON d1.PK_data1 = d2.data1
JOIN data3 d3 ON d2.PK_data2 = d3.data2
```

But this query returns additional data that shouldn't be there. I suspect that since the joins run at the same time it makes a relation between all the tables which is not correct. I think I should link `data3` with `data1`.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If the relationship between the tables is not one-to-one, this query can return multiple rows for a single row in `data1`. If you only want the unique combinations of `data1` and `ext`, try `SELECT d1.PK_data1, d3.ext FROM data1 d1 JOIN data2 d2 ON d1.PK_data1 = d2.data1 JOIN data3 d3 ON d2.PK_data2 = d3.data2 GROUP BY d1.PK_data1, d3.ext`

Comment: "I suspect that since the joins run at the same time it makes a relation between all the tables which is not correct." - definitely not, please show some sample data and expected results, because we don't know what "throws me additional data that shouldn't be there" means. The normal issue people run into with joins is getting multiple rows due to more than 1 record matching the condition.

Answer (score -1):

You can expect duplicate/multiple records since your join is on data1/data2 columns with primary key column unless the data columns are unique. The simple solution would be a distinct, but it may have a detrimental impact. If you are expecting only unique values in data2 and data3 for join column, you can specify unique constraint on those columns which would be the best option.